# How can I clear the jQuery DOM cache?

Tags: jquery, caching, dom, jquery-mobile

How can I clear the jQuery DOM cache? I am still in the middle of developing and testing a jQuery Mobile application, and I keep seeing old versions of my code pop up and try to be executed.  Maybe it's because I used data-dom-cache="true" in some places? I've restarted my web server, but that doesn't fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: DOM cache resides by nature on the client, so restarting your web server is next to useless emptying it. Have you disabled the cache in your browser? That way the cache gets emptied between every page load.

Comment: The [first page is always cached](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3249) which I find very confusing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660934/how-does-one-disable-caching-in-jquery-mobile-ui

Answer (score -1):

You can use some JavaScript to find your element in the DOM Cache and delete it from there :-

```
$.domCache('#foo').remove();
```

Where `#foo` is the id of the your object.

I don't believe (although could be mistaken) that there is't a .clear function, so you'd need to loop through all existing elements previously cached for you.

Comment: Hi, I haven't seen the construct $.domCache(..) before. Can you link to some documentation?

Answer (score -1):

$.domCache doesn't work for me, but I came up with other solution:

```
function clearjQueryCache(){
    for (var x in jQuery.cache){
        delete jQuery.cache[x];
    }
}
```