# jquery mobile mvc 3 layout an partial views

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a project in .net with mvc 3, I'm trying to implement jquery mobile but I have some issues with custom js, here is part of the code of the _Layout.Mobile.cshtml

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="div_layout">
<div data-role="header">
    <a href="/" data-icon="home">Inicio</a>
    <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
    @RenderBody()
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Footer text</h4>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">...</script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/Content/js/utilities.js")">
</script>
</body>
```

The result html is (image link):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QXQk.png

The _LogOnPartial partial view use some functions in the utilities.js file, the thing is that this js file must be after the partial view, if not it doesnt work, until here everything's fine, but when I submit forms in the body section all the code in data-role="content" is duplicated and placed at bottom, here's the html result (image link):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Jsmq.png

so the content in the _LogOnPartial partial view stops working, the config file has ajaxEnabled: true, when I disable the ajax everything works fine but I'd like to use the jq mobile transitions, also I could not show loading message with ajaxEnabled: false, Could Somebody help to workaround this? thanks in advance.

Ok thanks for the answer, the _LogOnPartial partial view code is

```
<div id = "loginbox">
    <div class="User">
        <label for="login_user">Usuario:</label>
        <input id="login_user" name="login_user" type="text" required id="basic" value="" data-mini="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="Password">
        <label for="login_password">Contraseña:</label>
        <input id="login_password" name="login_password" type="password" required id="basic" value="" data-mini="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="boton_login">
        <button type="submit" id="login" data-theme="a">Login</button>
    </div>
    <div id="login_error_message">
        <span id="login_error_message_desc"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

part of the content of utilities.js is

```
$("#login").click(function () {
    alert('this never happens');
    //something
});
```

when the page load for the first time it works fine, but then it stops working (when the ajax duplicate the content)

Answer (score 0):

Without more code it is hard to say a solution. What does utilities.js do? What exactly is in LogOnPartial?

The problem you are facing with the duplicated data-role="content" is due to jquery mobile's DOM caching http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-cache.html When you disable Ajax then this feature is no longer required, which is why you aren't having issues anymore.

You can look at this answer [How does one disable Caching in jQuery Mobile UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660934/how-does-one-disable-caching-in-jquery-mobile-ui) which shows a method to remove the page as it is hidden.

Comment: Tanks for answer, I also tried to put the custom js in the _LogOnPartial partial view,when the site is loaded for the first time works fine, then when the content is inserted into the DOM, line <script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/Content/js/utilities.js")"></script> is not included it's like jquery mobile filters the content, I'm gonna check out the jquery events

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't so much that the content is duplicated, but that you aren't registering your callbacks after the new content is loaded. Your click handler was set for `$('#login')` when the initial content was loaded, but you'd need to re-set that handler for new content.

Check out the Events documentation for which event to subscribe to: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html

What jQuery Mobile does is make an AJAX request to the URL, and inserts the content into the DOM. That new content will then need to be hooked up.