# jQuery Mobile - stop caching

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In my case links loading into a special div's wrapers which are parents of its links.
I do it through `pageload` event.

All is ok when JQuery Mobile does AJAX requests. But if I click on visited link, jquery mobile doesn't send the request, but show me blank page, replace `#page1` content from cache in other words.

I need these requests.

**UPD**

Events `pagebeforeload`, `pageload` dont appear in cache case. =\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify to not cache the page like this :

```
<div data-role="page" id="page-detail" data-dom-cache="false">  
    ....
</div>
```

**Update**

In fact it is `data-dom-cache=false`, available for page, **link** and dialog

Doc http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/data-attributes.html

If you want avoid data prefecting for all pages, have a look here : [How does one disable Caching in jQuery Mobile UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660934/how-does-one-disable-caching-in-jquery-mobile-ui)

Answer (score -1):

Bite my code please

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeload', function(event, data) {
    var url = data.url;
    if (url.toLowerCase().indexOf("office") >= 0) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get(data.absUrl, {}, function(res){
            _this = $(res);
            if (_this.attr('data-id')>0) { 
                var card_id = _this.attr('data-id');
                $('#detail-'+card_id).empty().append(_this).trigger('create');
            }
        });
        data.deferred.reject( data.absUrl, data.options );
    }
});
```