# Prevent jQuery mobile link caching

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile, browser-cache

I have a asp.net website with some header links in `master` page. For some of them I added link to jQuery mobile script to format those specific pages (forms) to look good on phones/tablets.

But after I load one of those pages and then click on some other page, it somehow caches the current page and although I can see the correct page being loaded for split second, it then reloads previous page. I don't know why this happens, but I know that culprit is the jQm link, because if I remove it, it works like expected (without the mobile design though).

I don't use `data-role="page"` attribute or anything, just classic asp.net page.

Comment: Have you checked this: [jQuery Mobile - stop caching](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14951443/1351076) ?

Comment: Yes, I put data-dom-cache="false" in master links.. it doesn't work.

Comment: JQM isn't just only a CSS framework such that pages looks good in small screens, it is a full-featured framework for mobile which includes an own complete navigation system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile uses it's own kind of navigation model by default. It injects multiple specifically formatted pages into current page using AJAX. You probably need to disable it using code snippet below:

```
$( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
  $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

For more information check jQuery Mobile documentation [navigation model](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/navigation-linking-pages) and [global configuration](https://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config) pages.

Comment: This works after second click, weird. Will report back tomorrow.

Comment: Make sure that you bind `mobileinit` event handler before you load jQuery Mobile.