# Header back button with forced refreshing

Tags: jquery-mobile

I needed to force refreshing using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6536496/314051). When I navigate to a new page jQM correctly adds a back button in my header. But when I go back to the first page the back button incorrectly appears. Is it possible to conditionally create a back button? I have tried manually creating a back button and conditionally hiding it based on a parameter in the URI but it seems that once the button appears I can never hide it again.

Edit:
Here is some code that demonstrates the problem. Not only does it not hide the custom back button when you go back to page 1, but it doesn't hide the "page 1" content when you are on page 2, or visa versa. It seems that once something has been shown it cannot be rehidden.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var backButtonVar = null;
            var page1Var = null;
            var page2Var = null;
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="false">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Test</h1>
                <a id="backButton" data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left">MyBack</a>
            </div>

            <div id="page1" data-role="content">
                <a href="index.html?id=2">Go to page 2</a>
            </div>

            <div id="page2" data-role"content">
                This is page 2
            </div>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    jQuery(document).on('pagehide', 'div', function(event, ui) {
                        var page = jQuery(event.target);
                        page.remove();
                    });

                    backButtonVar = $('#backButton');
                    page1Var = $('#page1');
                    page2Var = $('#page2');
                    // Is this the root?
                    if (window.location.search == '') {
                        backButtonVar.hide();
                        page1Var.show()
                        page2Var.hide()
                    } else {
                        backButtonVar.show();
                        page1Var.hide()
                        page2Var.show()
                    }
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not changing pages here, hence, `pagehide` event won't trigger. What you're trying to do is to show/hide contents within the same page.

Comment: Actually it seems that it does. If I put an `alert('foo');` in the `on('pagehide')` function it fires with every page change.

Comment: It should fire when you change pages, but if you show/hide div within the same page, it won't. However, you have one page only in the code above. check this answer, let me know if this is what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374046/jquery-mobile-back-buttons/16374970#16374970

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. In `pagebeforeshow` I'm now doing a `backButtonVar.hide()` if we are on page one, and in `pagebeforehide` I'm doing a `backButtonVar.remove()`. If you want to supply your comment above as the Answer I'll mark it as such. And if you can maybe explain why the `.remove()` is needed. I would have thought `.hide()` would have been sufficient. Thanks!

Comment: Ill add it as an answer, but let me explain it for you. JQM adds back button dynamically to each page except for the first page you open and home page of course. This fix adds button to direct the user to home page and removes it once navigates away, in order not to conflict and overlap with the dynamically add button by JQM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the fix. Give the back-button a class `backButton`. `.hide()` it if the active page is the home page `page1`, else `.show()` it.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/u99J8/)**

```
$('.backButton').hide();
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
 var activePage = $.mobile.activePage;
 if (activePage[0].id != 'page1') {
  $('.backButton').show();
 }
 else {
  $('.backButton').hide();
 }
});
```

If you have any question, please let me know.