# Jquery Mobile Back Buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an application in which I am programmatically add a back button to the page. This means that the first page will not have a back button on it. However the app itself has many ways of entering the app, in other words I can get a notification and in touching that notification it goes to a particular area in the app. This area will not have a backbutton to go to the homepage, and if I add one manually it will conflict with the programmed back button.

So I am looking for a way to add a button to go back to the homepage only when the page is loaded first and other times when you visit the page the back button performs as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you're using `data-add-back-btn=true` to dynamically add `data-rel=back` buttons to your pages. Hence, it is possible by first, checking if there is no `data-rel=back` in the active page *and* secondly, it is not your **Home** page.

One more thing, you need to remove that button once you navigate away from that page in order not to overlap with the one that JQM will generate.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/BvUSr/)**

```
var backbtn = '<a href="#home" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" class="backbtn"></a>';

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
 var activePage = $.mobile.activePage;
 if (activePage.find('[data-rel=back]').length === 0 && activePage[0].id != 'home') {
  activePage.find('[data-role=header] h1').before(backbtn);
 }
 $('[data-role=page]').trigger('pagecreate');
 $(document).on('pagebeforehide', function () {
  $('a.backbtn').remove();
 });
});
```

Comment: I was wondering if it made sense to do it this way. When the only page  you should be able to navigate to on pressing back is the homepage. Then it should just be a simple changepage function added to a button. Thing of it like a notification for a post in a facebook app. The only place you should be able to go to in pressing back on a notification should be the homepage.

Comment: @KernElliott This example makes the button look native when placed in the header. Also, you need to check whether this page has a button or not and that it's not the home page. Using ChangePage requires some code as well.