# jqm data-rel="back" issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, back

**imagine the following scenario:**

i have a jquery-mobile formular, it´s results are linking to its resultpage.

on the resultpage i have this back button:

```
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button"></a>
```

this works fine to just update the content and keep the submitted form data,

**but**
what if a user came from a search-engine or similiar extern link, then my back button links back to the searchengine/externLink .

so how do i Differentiate between those who came from my form or anywhere else in a jqm-way ?

i have a "start-search-page" i would love to link to if the user didn´t came from the search and i don´t want to miss the ajax-link from my search to the resultpage, use the same button and idealy i don´t have to set any cookie.

is there any hint or smarter attempt than check the server url from document.referrer ?
thanks in advance

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374046/jquery-mobile-back-buttons

Comment: thanks but that doesnt help me, because in my case there´s always a button '[data-rel=back]' inside the searchresultpage

Comment: This will check if a particular page was the first page to view, and accordingly sets the back button to home or wherever you want. If a user is navigating your page normally, it will act as a rel=back.

Comment: okay you are right, but this doesnt work for my as i use groovy-layout template engine and the search and searchresult is inside the same data-role="page"

Comment: okay  it doesn´t work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check current page url using below code:

```
var prevUrl = $.mobile.activePage.data('url');
```

in case u want to perform different actions based on previous URL.
then on save the URL in the global javascript variable and on click of the button check the previous URL and do the your functionality. eg

Before Navigating to page:

```
var prevUrl = $.mobile.activePage.data('url');
```

on click of button:

```
if (prevUrl=="myurl") {
//do something
 $.mobile.changePage('#search')
}
else {
 $.mobile.changePage('#nothing')
}
```