# Jquery Mobile $('#idoftheinputfield').val() always returns the first value entered

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

After looking at several related posts for couple of days I decided to post this question for which I still don't have an answer.

I have a jquery mobile page with an input field of type "search" and have a keyup function for the field to call another page with the current value of the field if an enter key is pressed. Every thing works fine first time I type in a value and press the enter key. But then on , it always gets the very first value (previous value) I entered and never gets the newly changed value.  I have seen related posts, but couldn't figure out the solution for my issue. Issue is same on all browsers I had tested so far, on computer and on mobile.

Here is input field

```
<div class="content-primary" data-dom-cache="false">
        <input type="search" name="finddata" id="search-team" value="Find Data" data-inline="true"/>
</div>
```

Here is the script function

```
$(document).on('keyup','#search-team',hndlSearchTmKeyup);

function hndlSearchTmKeyup(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
         alert("search!oo! ="+$("#search-team").val());     
         window.location.assign("/myapp/mysearchpage.jsp?findTmNm="+$("#search-team").val())
         return false;
    }
}
```

After further testing I found out that if I just display an alert in the hndlSearchTmKeyup function without calling the window.location.assign it displays the new value correctly. When I include the window.location.assign and from the next page when I click the "home" button and return to the original page and again type in a new value and press enter it shows the old value.  Not sure what is going on.

Comment: Not sure what is causing the problem you describe, but I notice in your `keyUpFunc(e)` you have the event object parameter declared as `e` but then you use `event` in two places inside the function where it should be `e`. In your second function you should be able to just use `event.which` directly - jQuery normalises `which` so you don't need to test for `event.keyCode`. (Also I don't understand why you have the two functions - both test for key 13, which seems a bit redundant.)

Comment: Just a suggestion, instead of this `var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;`, you can simply do this `var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which`

Comment: @nnnnnn and Palash Mondal , thanks for your suggestions , cleaned up the code, and now I found out the issue doesn't happen if I just display an alert. It happens when I include the window.location.assign , go the next page, and come back to the page using the "home" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research it appears it is related to a known issue in jquery mobile where the first page is cached no matter what.

[How does one disable Caching in jQuery Mobile UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660934/how-does-one-disable-caching-in-jquery-mobile-ui/13558786#13558786).

I implemented one of the workarounds documented in that thread to fix the issue (the one suggested by @KCD)