# When exactly is JQM DOM cache emptied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am constantly refreshing a `<div>` element with JQM which contains several bindings. After every refresh, I see an increase of listeners in Chrome. At some point, the page is not responsive anymore.

According to the documentation, `html()` replaces (i.e. invoked `empty()`) all related elements of that `<div>` (including bindings) before inserting new content, however, that would mean that the listeners do not increase. Even when I delete the `<div>` element using `remove()` and recreate, the numbers of listeners do not decrease. Is that somehow related to the DOM cache, which is not being emptied maybe? I only have a single page, and as I have learned, the first page is always cached.

What am I overseeing here?

Simplified version of my main document:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).on("pagecreate", function( event ) {
 
    var interval;
    setRefreshTime();
 
    function setRefreshTime() {
        interval = setTimeout(function () { refresh(); }, 10000);
    }
 
    function refresh() {
        clearTimeout(interval);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "content.php",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#content").html(data);
                $("#content").enhanceWithin();
                setRefreshTime();
             }
        });
    }
    
 
    $("#page").on("click", ".function_A", function(){
        refresh();
    });
    
    $("#page").on("click", ".function_B", function(){
        refresh();
    });
    
    });
 
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div id="content"><?php include("content.php");?></div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

`content.php` which gets loaded:

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="a">
    <li data-role="list-divider">Title A</li>
    <li data-role="list-divider">Title B</li>
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all function_A" >Button A</a></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all function_B" >Button B</a></div>
        </div>
 </ul>
```

EDIT: Thanks for the comments so far. I took everything into account (I basically replaced the  (content) to be replaced with the page-; When re-running the performance monitoring, I do not see the duplicate bindings, but still an increase in listeners. Please find the screenshot below:

[image: Performance view]

Could it be that it is actually not JQM related but an ajax "issue"?

In rar cases, there is a sudden drop in the number of listeners:

[image: Rare case when listeners drop suddenly]

How can I provoke the latter?

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark, but any chance that this works for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14519319/3825777

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately no success... There isn't any option about caching in the current release. I tried to turn off ```ajaxEnabled``` (since I do not really use the default JQM ajax), however, there is no change at all.

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery Mobile Documentation](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/pages/):

> Within the "`page`" [...] the immediate children of a "`page`" are divs
> with data-role="`header`", class="`ui-content`", and data-role="`footer`".

In Your project, You are dynamically updating the `content`, which is one level below the `page`. You need to check what kind of `widget` You are dynamically append to the `content`, because some widgets needs to attach event listeners to an upper level - the `page` - to provide some functionalities, like - for instance - the `header` and `footer` for the *tap-toggle*, or the `navbar` for the *active state* button, or moreover, the `panel` widget for swipe, and so on.

Are You able to identify inside the Developer Tools the duplicated event listeners?

**The `navbar` example:**

Lets take for example the `navbar`: the JQM team intended this widget to be attached one time to a page to provide navigation among pages. If You are dynamically append a `navbar` it is not enough to clean-up the parent markup (which is also correctly detaching the direct attached event listeners) but You need also to clean-up the event listeners attached to the page during the widget creation.

**Why the `navbar` widget doesn't remove all created event listeners?**

I am not the right person to judge if this is a bug or a missing feature, *Everything* can be implemented in a better way. As said, the `navbar` is meant to be inserted just one time inside a page to provide navigation among pages.

**Is there a fix for the dynamic `navbar`?**

For the event listeners issue, You may need to monkey-patch JQM like this:

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
        $.widget("mobile.navbar", $.mobile.navbar, {
            _destroy: function() {
                var $navbar = this.element;
                $navbar.closest(".ui-page").off("pagebeforeshow");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

**The result:**

**Left:** the `page` event listeners despite the `content.empty()` or `content.html("")` invocations.

**Right:** the `page` event listeners with the hotfix applied.

[image]

---

So, I strongly believe this is not a JQM Page cache issue. Every `widget` has its own implementation and behavior. If You are using just only one page and dynamically updating the content, this is fine, but - depending from which widget You are appending inside the page content - You may need to apply a custom clean-up or You may need to replace the widget with something simpler: for instance, a good replacement for the `navbar` buttons is a `controlgroup` with radio-buttons. No extra unknown functionalities and no need to special clean-up.