# How can I change a class and keep it in a Nav menu with jQuery mobile

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-navbar

I spend about all the after noon looking to solve that issue (I work with jQuery mobile 1.4.5).

I dynamically create a menu at the footer, this way:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", function(event) {

    var $maPage = $(event.target);
        var html    = '<div data-role="navbar">'
                + '<ul id="menu">'
                + '<li><a href="#home" data-rel="location" data-icon="location" data-transition="slide"></a></li>'
                + '<li><a href="#graph" data-rel="graph" data-icon="bars" data-transition="slide"></a></li>'
                + '<li><a href="#alarm" data-rel="alert" data-icon="alert" data-transition="slide" id="link-alarm" class="green"></a></li>'
        + '<li><a href="#preferences" data-rel="preferences" data-icon="gear" data-role="button" data-transition="slide"></a></li>'
                + '<li><a href="#info" data-rel="info" data-icon="info" data-transition="slide"></a></li>'
                 + '</ul>'
                + '</div>';
    
    // On transforme mon HTML brut en objet jQuery pour le manipuler facillemrnt
    var $navBar = $(html);
    // On recupère l'Id de la page en cours
    var idPage = $maPage.attr('id');
    
    // On recupère le bouton qui corresponf a l'id de la page en cours, pour lui ajouter les classes ui-btn-active et ui-state-persist
    //$navBar.find('a[href="#' + idPage + '"]').addClass('ui-btn-active ui-state-persist');
    
    $maPage.find('div[data-role="footer"]').html($navBar);
});
```

On the alarm link, the is a class green which add a green background when there is no alarm.

I created a temporary function to change the class. It looking at a localStorage variable which is 0 when the is no alarm, and the number increase depending if the amount of the alarms

```
function checkRed() {
   /*
    * Journal
    */
    
    ls_journal = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('journal'));
    //alert(ls_journal.length);

    if(ls_journal.length > 0) {
        //alert('add red');
        $('#link-alarm').removeClass('green').addClass("red");
    }
    else
    {
        //alert('add green');
       $('#link-alarm').removeClass('red').addClass('green');
    }
}
```

On the Home page, there is map with the localisation of stations. A MySQL request is requesting the status of the station and when a temperature is too low, an alarm ring, and the alarm link background has to be red.

That's works fine as long as I am on the Home page, but when I move to the other page, the transition does not occur. I mean the Alarm link background remains green with the class green.

Sometime it's red, but mostly of the time is green.

I believe my issue may be related to the Handler, but I tried to call the `checkRed()` function on different Handler

```
$(document).on( "pagecontainertransition", function( event, data ) {
        checkRed();
        //$('#menu').listview(); // That do not work well
});

$(document).on( "pageshow", function( event, data ) {
        checkRed();
        //$('#menu').listview(); // That do not work well
});

$(document).on( "pagecontainertshow", function( event, data ) {
        checkRed();
        //$('#menu').listview(); // That do not work well
});
```

My goal is really simple but I got so issue to make it working, and I would really appreciate your help

```
ls_journal = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('journal'));
```

When ls_journal is greater than 0, then alarm backgroud link must always be green, from all pages after a transition (pagebeforecreate, pageshow, etc).

And when id is equal to zero, the background must be green.

I really wonder, if there is way to refresh the nav, at certain point of time ?
I tried without success

```
$('#menu').listview()
$('#menu').listview('refresh');
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: The unordered list inside a `navbar` widget is **not** enhanced as a `listview`. When You place a `ul` inside a `navbar` widget, the framework will create a [grid](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/grids/). You may notice that there isn't any attribute `data-role="listview"`. So, You won't find the `listview` object attached to Your `ul`. Beside this, the `navbar` widget is meant to be placed inside a web-app just only one time, to provide global navigation. If Your "pagebeforecreate" event is triggered more than one time, the navbars will overlap. You overcomplicated it, keep it simple.

Comment: Hello deblocker, Thank for the clarification. I am not very sure about the second part of your comment. <code>var $maPage = $(event.target);</code> and <code>var idPage = $maPage.attr('id');</code> get the page id and then I add the fotter at the footer section of it own page. It never add at the same location <code>$maPage.find('div[data-role="footer"]').html($navBar);</code>

Comment: Sorry, From your code cannot understand why You need more than one `navbar`. I strongly suggest You to use an `external footer` and just one `navbar`. Please take a look at this demo here: [Persistent navbar in a fixed footer toolbar](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/toolbar-fixed-persistent/). The `navbar` is not just only a CSS skin, but it will also install some upper-level handlers (You can check my previous answer here: [The navbar example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65482061/4845566))